# How to setup hyperledger fabric explorer | amazon managed blockchain

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-explorer, amazon-managed-blockchain

I setup hyperledger fabric network using amazon managed blockchain by following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/managed-blockchain-get-started-tutorial.html). Everything works properly in the hyperledger network. Now I want to setup [hyperledger explorer](https://www.hyperledger.org/use/explorer). I can not find any amazon's official document to setup hyperledger fabric explorer. So I am following [this article](https://medium.com/@rdg7739/aws-managedblockchain-hyperledger-explorer-quickstart-final-6479b8462edb). As author's suggestion, I cloned [this repo](https://github.com/rdg7739/blockchain-explorer). I have done everything as the author said in this article. Now I need to edit `first-network.json` file. I edited the `first-network.json` file, as the following,

```
{
    "name": "first-network",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "client": {
        "tlsEnable": true,
        "adminUser": "admin",
        "adminPassword": "adminpw",
        "enableAuthentication": false,
        "organization": "m-QMD*********6HK",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                },
                "orderer": "300"
            }
        }
    },
    "channels": {
        "mychannel": {
            "peers": {
                "nd-JEFEX**************N4": {}
            },
            "connection": {
                "timeout": {
                    "peer": {
                        "endorser": "6000",
                        "eventHub": "6000",
                        "eventReg": "6000"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1MSP": {
            "mspid": "m-QMD*********6HK",
            "fullpath": true,
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/fabric-path/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/1bebc656f198efb4b5bed08ef42cf3b2d89ac86f0a6b928e7a172fd823df0a48_sk"
            },
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "/fabric-path/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem"
            }
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "nd-JEFEX**************N4": {
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/fabric-path/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
            },
            "url": "grpcs://nd-JEFEX**************N4.m-QMD*********6HK.n-rf*********q.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:30003",
            "eventUrl": "grpcs://nd-JEFEX**************N4.m-QMD*********6HK.n-rf*********q.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:30003",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "nd-JEFEX**************N4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is what should I add in the place of adminPrivateKey-path, signedCert-path, tlsCACerts-path.
Here is my list of available files generated while [setting up hyperledger hyperledger fabric in amazon managed blockchain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/managed-blockchain-get-started-tutorial.html).

```
/home/ec2-user/admin-msp$ ls * -r
user:

signcerts:
cert.pem

keystore:
fd84a**********************1f03ff_sk

cacerts:
ca-m-*****-n-*****-managedblockchain-us-east-1-amazonaws-com-30002.pem

admincerts:
cert.pem
```

Help me to setup hyperledger fabric explorer for my hyperledger fabric network.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your connection profile as below:

```
  "organizations": {
    "Org1MSP": {
      "mspid": "m-QMD*********6HK",
      "fullpath": true,
      "adminPrivateKey": {
        "path": "/home/ec2-user/admin-msp/keystore/fd84a**********************1f03ff_sk"
      },
      "signedCert": {
        "path": "/home/ec2-user/admin-msp/signcerts/cert.pem"
      }
    }
  },
  "peers": {
    "nd-JEFEX**************N4": {
      "tlsCACerts": {
        "path": "/home/ec2-user/admin-msp/cacerts/ca-m-*****-n-*****-managedblockchain-us-east-1-amazonaws-com-30002.pem"
      },
      "url": "grpcs://nd-JEFEX**************N4.m-QMD*********6HK.n-rf*********q.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:30003",
      "grpcOptions": {
        "ssl-target-name-override": "nd-JEFEX**************N4"
      }
    }
  }
```

And I recommend to use the latest Explorer because commit for AWS managed blockchain service and many other bugfixes were committed recently ([Making Hyperledger Explorer compatible to Amazon Managed Blockchain N… · hyperledger/blockchain-explorer@7b30821](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/commit/7b308219b1cdcb2f9e5aa30a51ecd35cbbf68fca))